# How do I generate data that have the same mean, standard deviation but very different shapes or distributions in R?

Tags: r, mean, standard-deviation

How do I generate data that have the same mean, standard deviation but very different shapes or distributions? Below is one answer from jthetzel on how to create data with the same mean and standard deviation but I need help on how to make it non-normal. Ideally, I would like graphs of widely different shapes that share the same mean and standard deviation.

```
#install.packages("Runuran")
library(Runuran)
## Discrete normal distribution bounded between 0 and 100
# Create UNU.RAN discrete distribution object
discrete <- unuran.discr.new(pv = dnorm(0:100, mean = 50, sd = 25), lb = 0, ub = 100)

# Create UNU.RAN object using the Guide-Table Method for Discrete Inversion
unr <- unuran.new(distr = discrete, method = "dgt")

# Generate random variates from the UNU.RAN object
d2 <- ur(unr = unr, n = 1000)

summary(d2)
sd(d2)
hist(d2)
```

Comment: I don't know what it means to generate non-parametric data, especially since you specify parameters (mean and standard deviation).  Any given distribution (except infinite-variance ones like the Cauchy distribution) can be translated and scaled to a given mean and variance, but you can't talk about generating data without some underlying distribution.

Comment: @user295691 I used the word non-parametric incorrectly. Basically, I want to generate data that have different shapes but have the same mean and standard deviation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take any set of numbers generated from any distribution and translate/scale it to have the desired standard deviation.  In vanilla R, these functions look like r* -- `runif`, `rnorm`, `rbeta`, `rpois`, `rlnorm`, etc.  See `?Distributions` for a list of the built-in distributions supported.

Even distributions that don't have a finite variance can be abused in this way.

```
d1 <- rcauchy(1000)
d2 <- 12 * (d1 - mean(d1)) / sd(d1) + 5
sd(d2)   # will be 12
mean(d2) # will be 5
```

For convenience, here's a function that will do this

```
shoehorn <- function(d, desired.mean, desired.sd) { 
  desired.sd * (d - mean(d)) / sd(d) + desired.mean
}
```